# Django: ModelForm get ManyToMany Field in clean Function

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have a Model called Order and it's it has manytomanyfield to ProductModel

i want to get the values of selected products in clean function to make some calculations

but i cannot find product field

this is the modelform code

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean_points(self):
        products = self.cleaned_data["Product"]
        print(self.cleaned_data.get(
            'product', None))

        points = 20
        self.set_customer_points(self.cleaned_data["customer"], points=points)

        return points

    def set_customer_points(self, customer, points=0):
        customer.points = customer.points + points
        customer.save()
```

and this is OrderModel

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, )
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    order_state = models.ForeignKey(
        'OrderState', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    product = models.ManyToManyField(
        "product.Product", )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.name




class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products",)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (lower case)?
If it doesn't work, print(self.cleaned_data) and see the available fields for debugging.

```
def clean_points(self):
    products = self.cleaned_data.get("product")
```